# PDO fetchAll() - json_encode doesn't work when using JOIN

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm using `PDO` to fetch all rows from a table:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=learning', 'root', '');

$query = $pdo->preapre("
    SELECT * 
    FROM people 
    INNER JOIN city
    ON 
    people.id = city.person_id
");
$query->execute();

$people = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now at this point if i `print_r` this `$people` variable i'm getting a multidimensional array that contains all those rows from that table:

```
Array
(
    [0]=>Array
        (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Emma
        [city] => New York
        )
    [1]=>Array
        (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => John
        [city] => Los Angeles
        )
    //and so on
)
```

But if i want to `json_encode` that `$people` variable and then echo it i'm getting a blank screen:

```
$j = json_encode($people);
echo $j;
```

I think i'm doing something pretty wrong but i don't understand what, can somebody please help me understand and fix this?

Thank you! :D

**UPDATE**

On using `var_dump`:

```
var_dump($j);
```

I'm getting:

```
bool(false)
```

P.S I should mention that i changed the query to an `INNER JOIN` - without `INNER` the `json_encode` worked

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death // `->preapre` // `json_last_error` //  `var_dump` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up your `charset` to UTF8 in your `pdo` connection:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=learning;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
//your code
```